# Understanding Cassandra system.peers Query using C# Driver

Tags: c#, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am not sure why i am getting the same peer as of the contact point when i query peers table from node 1.

when i change the ip to 46(node2) i get 45(node1) , but querying from 45(node1) i am getting 45(node1)

```
        Cluster clusterconn = Cluster.Builder().WithCredentials(txtuser.Text, txtsec.Text).AddContactPoint("192.168.0.45).Build();
        ISession Conn_session = clusterconn.Connect("system");

        var con_result = Conn_session.Execute("select peer FROM system.peers");


     //   lstnode.Items.Add(txt_pip.Text);


        foreach (var rows in con_result)
        {

            //var value = row.GetValue<int>("id");

            lstnode.Items.Add(rows["peer"].ToString());



        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing the effect of the driver's load balancing policy. `system.peers` is a local table that is different on each node. When you execute queries using the driver, it will load balance among nodes, giving different results each time.

If you execute and print the results multiple times, you should see the peer alternate between your nodes.

Read some about load balancing policies [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/2.5/common/drivers/reference/tuningPolicies_c.html).

Comment: What can i do to always hit on one of the selected nodes? rather using drivers load balancing policy

Comment: Some drivers have something called a WhiteList load balancing policy that can be used to limit connected nodes. That's not implemented for C#. Two options:
- run the query twice (hitting two distinct nodes) and merge the results
- If you're just interested in cluster discovery, just use the driver Metadata API: http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/csharp/2.5/html/T_Cassandra_Metadata.htm